# R - pull title for corrplot graph within map in a pipeline

Tags: r

Imagine this piece of code:

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_split(cyl) %>% 
    map(select, mpg, disp, hp) %>% 
    `names<-`(c(4, 6, 8)) %>% 
    map(cor)
```

The names of the list elements are set according to the value of the `cyl` variable, based on which the data was split into three groups.

Now imagine passing all of this to `corrplot`:

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_split(cyl) %>% 
    map(select, mpg, disp, hp, cyl) %>% 
    `names<-`(c(4, 6, 8)) %>% 
    map(cor) %>% 
    map(corrplot)
```

Works nicely. Now, the `corrplot` function has a `title` argument, which is used to print titles on the plot. I want the title of each plot to be pulled from the name of the list element which was used to create the plot - in other words, those values of the `cyl` variable that were mentioned previously. How can I do this? I tried doing this:

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_split(cyl) %>% 
    map(select, mpg, disp, hp) %>% 
    `names<-`(c(4, 6, 8)) %>% 
    map(cor) %>% 
    map(corrplot, title = names(.))
```

But this just prints ALL the names on the graph and not just the ones from the current element.

If you have a solution, I would be very thankful. Without breaking the pipeline, because I can find the workaround with breaking the pipeline quite easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `imap/iwalk` instead of `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(corrplot)
mtcars %>% 
    group_split(cyl) %>% 
    map(select, mpg, disp, hp) %>% 
    `names<-`(c(4, 6, 8)) %>% 
    map(cor) %>% 
   imap(~ corrplot(.x, title = .y))
```

Comment: Thanks master. Could please explain again `names<-` How do you call this procedure or this counstruct. Many thanks!

Comment: @TarJae It is a setter function that sets the name (it is from the OP's code).  You may also use `setNames`.  There are certain functions that have getter and setter i.e. `names(mtcars)` or `names(lst1)` returns the column names and names of list as a getter function, whereas the `names<-`, is a setter